# Getting an exception "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, proximity

I am getting an exception

```
"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))" on the code for Proximity (Windows Phone 8)`

ProximityDevice device = ProximityDevice. GetDefault ();
```

Please let me know the reason

Answer (score 5):

Did you add to your project manifest the NFC capability? You need to open the WMAppManifest.xml file in visual studio, get to the Capabilities tab and select ID_CAP_PROXIMITY, then all is going to work :)

Comment: I forgot to add this.. now it's working.. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Windows Phone SDK as Admin ? If not you need to install it as admin to make it work.

[Click here for more info [taken form MSDN]](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/98845e23-71a8-4efc-a4dc-67773bda1613/access-is-denied-exception-from-hresult-0x80070005-eaccessdenied-in-windows-phone-sdk-80?forum=vssetup)